# WCF net tcp multiple client

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service *RService* and client *RClient*  configured with a net tcp binding. Once a client establishes a connection with RService the user ID is added to a Dictionary for later processing. RService has various methods that read/write from/to a database that can be called from a client.

All works well when there is one client active. When a 2nd client connects to RService, it is expected that the 2nd client's user ID is added to the dictionary. However, the first client's dictionary entry is removed and the 2nd client's user ID is added.

Creating and calling RService from the client:

```
service = new RecruitAidServiceClient("NetTcpBinding", new EndpointAddress(uri.Uri));
u = service.Authenticate(txtedtUsername.Text, txtedtPassword.Text);
```

Authenticate method signature in IRService (interface for service).

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(RServiceException))]
User Authenticate(string pUsername, string pPassword);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: Show your code that adds the client to your dictionary.  That's where the problem is, and without showing us that we can't help you.

Comment: You're service is probably using an `InstanceContextMode` of `PerCall`, which is (I believe) the default.  That means a new context is created for every call (and the dictionary is recreated).  In order to persist the data you want across multiple calls and clients, you have two options.  1.  Save the data in some sort of persistent store (database, file, etc).  2.  Use an `InstanceContextMode` of `Single`.  I'd explore the first route first, as singletons do not scale well.